# Android Studio - GitHub Push not working perfectly

Tags: android, git, github, android-studio

I want to upload my codes to GitHub, so I created a repository and uploaded the code initially. But the problem goes after that, when I try to push, Android Studio is telling that everything is done, but when I go to web, I see, everything is as like it was.

Let me share my screen shots here-

1-Starting commit

[image: Starting commit]

2 - Commit and push - I have selected "Commit and push" from the drop-down button-

[image: Commit and push]

3- find the success message

[image]

4- Nothing done in the reprosetory

[image]

The link of the repository is [here](https://github.com/abrarjahin/CustomListView-LocalImage), only 2 commits, one during the first commit and then I have added read me file in the web, only this 2 commits is existent.

The console log is like this-

```
13:35:30.985: cd C:\Android\CustomListview
13:35:30.999: git -c core.quotepath=false push --progress --porcelain cloud-platform refs/heads/master:master --tags
github --credentials get: github: command not found
github --credentials store: github: command not found
To https://source.developers.google.com/p/custom-list-view-with-image/r/default
=   refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master [up to date]
Done
```

Why is it not uploading?

Comment: Can you share the console log of Version Control?

Comment: What does `git remote -v` returns? What 'cloud-platform' refers to?

Comment: Thanks! I think the destination is wrong. It should be 
To https://github.com/abrarjahin/CustomListView-LocalImage.git? Please check the git repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

drawable can be pushed to GitHub as follows:

1. In the left panel of  Android studio, right click your drawable directory.
2. Choose git, add. `(Ctrl+Alt+A)`
3. Following steps are as usual.
4. Done!

Answer (score 1):

I used to push code using token;

Here is what i did for this issue:

1. in android studio opened terminal.
   [image]
2. entered

```
git push
```

3. when email and password were asked on gui, i closed the dialogue box.
4. after that i was prompted for user name on terminal, so i entered it.
5. after that i was asked password, where, instead of password, i entered the access token.

```
git push
Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt.
Username for 'https://github.com': xxxxx
Password for 'https://xxxxx@github.com': ____
```

and voila.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if git recognizes your `cloud-platform`.

```
$ git remote -v
```

And if it doesn't show you the link you are pushing it to, add it like this

```
$ git remote add cloud-platform https://github.com/abrarjahin/CustomListView-LocalImage.git
```